# Class 'Tests\DuskTestCase' not found in ExampleTest.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I am trying to run Laravel Dusk tests, but when I run the test, a new Chrome tab pops up with this message.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tests\DuskTestCase' not found in path-to-project\tests\Browser\ExampleTest.php on line 9
```

All I have done so far is run `composer require --dev laravel/dusk:^1.0` and `php artisan dusk:install`.

This is my ExampleTest.php (exactly how Laravel set it up)

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Laravel\Dusk\Chrome;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function ($browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }
}
```

DuskTestCase.php is also just as Laravel set it up and has the namespace `namespace Tests;`.

I am using Laravel 5.4 and Dusk 1.0. I am running the test through PhpStorm, using the work around described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416870/errors-running-laravel-dusk/47915171?noredirect=1#comment82862921_47915171).

Anyone know why DuskTestCase can't seem to be found, even though it appears to be set up correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the file `DuskTestCase.php` exists in `tests` directory? It yes, try running `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 5):

In composer.json:

add `"Tests\\": "tests/"` in

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

then, run `composer dump-autoload` to reload your packages.

Comment: This is excellent (and still needed for upgrading old projects), but put it in your ``autoload-dev`` instead, as per Laravel's latest default composer.json

Answer (score 4):

I had this error due to using out-of-date docs that didn't include this line:

`$ php artisan dusk:install`

Comment: WIth 'composer require --dev laravel/dusk' ,my tests directory has not DuskTestCase.php before. With this, It is generated & works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `composer dump-autoload` does not solve problem, you can try these steps.

1. Visit homepage in your browser and check if it renders properly. If not, then you probably have a problem with your webserver configuration (Hint: isn't your project subdirectory of document root?).
2. You can try Laravel inbuilt server via `php artisan serve`. If homepage is accessible in your browser now, then you can try dusk again.
   In that case, remember to update your .env file to match APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000,
   and run php artisan dusk from another cli window, cause `php artisan serve` needs to be running also.

Comment: The homepage does load. I configured the url with XAMPP, and that url is defined in .env. I tried doing 2, and the home page is accessible from http://127.0.0.1:8000, but when I run `php artisan dusk` I get `[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException] TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.` This was an error I saw previously, but thought I solved it when I got PhpStorm and and Dusk working.

Answer (score 1):

if you test using a phpstrom then u have set path of phpunit ......
in  settings/languages & framework/php/test frameworks and use composer autoloader path and then select a path of your laravel dusk project with autoload.php file.....
set file a vendor/autoload.php file in path to script...